# Install old version of mysql in 10.10

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, mysql

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, but I find that this project is having issues with the version of mysql server that 10.10 installs. I have another machine running the same build of this project but it's running 10.04 and it doesn't have any problems. I found that the version are a little different (10.04 has 5.1.41 and 10.10 has 5.1.49). I would like to be able to install the lucid version on my maverick machine, but Google isn't turning up anything useful to accomplish this task.

Anyone know how I would go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the "Synaptic Package Manager". You find the program under "System > Administration". Find the mysql-server package you have installed and select "Package > Force version..." as shown in the screenshot below.

This will show you a list of the available versions. If the version is not in the list you might need to add a new PPA for that, but I suggest you try this first.

[image]

Comment: The same action is available through apt-get. The command is "sudo apt-get install packagename=versioncode" package name would be "mysql-server" and versioncode something like "5.1.41-3ubuntu12.6".